# Ubuntu Zsh (via Vagrant) is not locating Zsh or its functions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, zsh

I have a Vagrant provisioning script that attempts to install Zsh if it's not available and then change the shell to use Zsh.

There are two issues I believe I'm having:

The first is I don't believe the shell to be changing to Zsh because when I run `vagrant ssh` to access the Ubuntu VM and once there run `ps -p $$` the command indicates Bash is the running shell (where I would have expected Zsh).

The second issue is, if it *is* changing to the Zsh shell (regardless of what `ps -p $$` reports back) then Zsh is displaying lots of errors when I source .zshrc file, which suggest the specified functions are missing or just not being referenced correctly.

---

I'll break it down into steps by doing the installation of Zsh manually rather than via a Vagrant provisioning script...

1. `cat /etc/shells` -> I see no reference to Zsh†
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install zsh`≠
4. `cat /etc/shells` -> there is now `/bin/zsh` and `/usr/bin/zsh`
5. `which zsh` -> `/usr/bin/zsh`
6. `zsh --version` -> `zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`
7. `chsh -s $(which zsh)`
8. `source .zshrc` -> Lots of errors sent to stdout~~
9. `tree /usr/share/zsh/` -> see below** for output, but notice `function` directory is not inside `5.0.2` directory?

I think it's more likely Zsh isn't being changed to, because if I execute the command `zsh` I get taken to a new shell environment and if I then run `source .zshrc` I get no errors. Also, if I run `ps -p $$` now I'll see Zsh being reported as the running shell.

My entire Vagrant provisioning script can be found at the bottom of this question.

† the list of shells I see are:

```
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/usr/bin/tmux
/usr/bin/screen
```

≠ the output is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  zsh-common
Suggested packages:
  zsh-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  zsh zsh-common
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,726 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main zsh-common all 5.0.2-3ubuntu6 [2,119 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main zsh amd64 5.0.2-3ubuntu6 [607 kB]
Fetched 2,726 kB in 6s (420 kB/s)                                              
Selecting previously unselected package zsh-common.
(Reading database ... 61742 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../zsh-common_5.0.2-3ubuntu6_all.deb ...
Unpacking zsh-common (5.0.2-3ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package zsh.
Preparing to unpack .../zsh_5.0.2-3ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zsh (5.0.2-3ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up zsh-common (5.0.2-3ubuntu6) ...
Setting up zsh (5.0.2-3ubuntu6) ...
update-alternatives: using /bin/zsh5 to provide /bin/zsh (zsh) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /bin/zsh5 to provide /bin/rzsh (rzsh) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/rzsh.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/zsh.1.gz (of link group rzsh) doesn't exist
```

~~ Below is the list of errors, while the Zsh config file can be seen here https://github.com/Integralist/dotfiles/blob/linux/.zshrc

```
autoload: command not found
zmodload: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
No command 'zstyle' found, did you mean:
 Command 'astyle' from package 'astyle' (universe)
 Command 'style' from package 'diction' (universe)
zstyle: command not found
bindkey: command not found
bindkey: command not found
bindkey: command not found
bindkey: command not found
bindkey: command not found
bindkey: command not found
bindkey: command not found
autoload: command not found
No command 'colors' found, did you mean:
 Command 'xcolors' from package 'xcolors' (universe)
colors: command not found
-bash: %{$fg_no_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_no_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_no_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_no_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_no_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_no_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_no_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_no_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
-bash: %{$fg_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}: bad substitution
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
unsetopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
No command 'setopt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'getopt' from package 'util-linux' (main)
setopt: command not found
autoload: command not found
```

** output from `tree` command on `/usr/share/zsh` directory:

```
/usr/share/zsh/
├── 5.0.2
│   └── scripts
│       └── newuser
├── functions
│   ├── Calendar
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── Calendar.zwc
│   ├── Chpwd
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── Chpwd.zwc
│   ├── Completion
│   │   ├── AIX
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── AIX.zwc
│   │   ├── Base
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── Base.zwc
│   │   ├── bashcompinit
│   │   ├── BSD
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── BSD.zwc
│   │   ├── compaudit
│   │   ├── compdump
│   │   ├── compinit
│   │   ├── compinstall
│   │   ├── Cygwin
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── Cygwin.zwc
│   │   ├── Darwin
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── Darwin.zwc
│   │   ├── Debian
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── Debian.zwc
│   │   ├── Linux
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── Linux.zwc
│   │   ├── Mandriva
│   │   │   ├── _rebootin
│   │   │   └── _urpmi
│   │   ├── Mandriva.zwc
│   │   ├── openSUSE
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── openSUSE.zwc
│   │   ├── Redhat
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── Redhat.zwc
│   │   ├── Solaris
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── Solaris.zwc
│   │   ├── Unix
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── Unix.zwc
│   │   ├── X
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── X.zwc
│   │   ├── Zsh
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── Zsh.zwc
│   ├── Completion.zwc
│   ├── Exceptions
│   │   ├── catch
│   │   └── throw
│   ├── Exceptions.zwc
│   ├── MIME
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── MIME.zwc
│   ├── Misc
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── Misc.zwc
│   ├── Newuser
│   │   └── zsh-newuser-install
│   ├── Newuser.zwc
│   ├── Prompts
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── Prompts.zwc
│   ├── TCP
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── TCP.zwc
│   ├── VCS_Info
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── VCS_Info.zwc
│   ├── Zftp
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── Zftp.zwc
│   ├── Zle
│   │   ├── ...
│   └── Zle.zwc
└── help
```

---

Here is my Vagrant provisioning script

```
# Install dependencies
add-apt-repository ppa:pi-rho/dev # for latest tmux
apt-get update
apt-get remove vim-tiny -y
apt-get install vim tmux git tree htop reptyr xclip -y

# Install Zsh shell if it's not available
if ! cat /etc/shells | grep zsh; then
  echo "Zsh is not available, so we'll install it now"
  apt-get install zsh -y
fi

# For the Reptyr program to work we need to enable system access
# We do this by changing the ptrace scope from one to zero
sed -i 's/kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1/kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0/' /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf

# Because this is a system control daemon, we need to restart the relevant service
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf

# Avoid the shell asking us to authorise the authenticity of github.com
# This happens when doing a git clone for the first time
echo -e "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config

# Install dotfiles...
dotfiles_location=/home/vagrant/dotfiles
git clone https://github.com/Integralist/dotfiles.git $dotfiles_location
cd $dotfiles_location && git fetch && git checkout linux

# Ensure we don't move unnecessary files
shopt -s extglob
mv !(.|..|.git|README.md) ..

# Clean-up
cd ../ && rm -rf dotfiles

# Change to Zsh shell
chsh -s $(which zsh)

# Source the Zsh config file
source .zshrc
```

Comment: upvoting your question becuase you clearly lay out the details of your problem. Next time, we probably don't need to see every bit of info, edit it down a little with notes like (similar error repeated 40+ times) ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chsh` only changes the default/login shell for the current user it does not change the *current* shell.

You either need to log back out and log in again or manually `exec zsh` to change the active/current shell.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! I was clearly being a doughnut :-/